# Can't mount cd/dvd r/w drive in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd, cd

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I'm having some troubles mounting my drive or getting it to detect media.

When I do this:
`dmesg | grep "sr0"`

I get :

```
[    2.096797] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    2.096968] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

when I:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/cdrom
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0

sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom 
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

There is most certainly media in the drive. 
Can someone please help me understand how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. Using my Acer laptop Ubuntu (Any version) doesn't recognize the DVD R/W Rom drive that's built in. I purchased an External DVD R/W and it seems to work fine. I know it isn't a solution but for the time being, it works. Until I can figure out the problem, I can still utilize other discs.

Pico